# Show all data from array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

My code Is

```
$co = count($da);
print_r($co);
foreach($da as $abc) {
  $myarray = array(
    date("j", strtotime($abc - > date)) => ''
  );
}
```

$da have four value but show only one record into calender I use

```
$data = $this->calendar->generate(2017,12, $myarray);
$this->load->view('calen',['va'=>$data]);
```

Screen shot of output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdo8S.png)

Into $da have four date store and pass this array into calender->generate but still show only one date highlight  that is last index date so how to solve this problem

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting the value of `$myarray` in every iteration of the loop

Change it to:

```
foreach($da as $abc) {
  $myarray[] = array(
        //^^ [] denotes new index in array
    date("j", strtotime($abc - > date)) => ''
  );
}
```

Comment: But when i can use this $myarray in the generate calendar that time only one date highlight or only one value are show i use foreach loop in  $dat=$this->calendar->generate(2017,12, $value); then only one date are highlight @charlietfl